# Como calcular o determinante de uma matriz em javascript?

Tags: javascript, matemática, matriz

Ex.: `det([-1, -2, 3], [3, 3, 1], [-1, 2, -3]) // retorna 22`

Ex.: `det([1, 2], [2, 5]) // retorna 1`

Ex.: `det([8]) // retorna 8`

Comment: A pergunta é sobre a matemática do cálculo, ou sobre a implementação em JavaScript?

Comment: A implementação em javascript

Comment: Esses links podem ser de alguma ajuda: http://paczynski.net/testarea/matrix.html e http://numericjs.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu criei a seguinte função em 2010, mas fiz algumas melhorias há pouco tempo:

```
function determinante(a) {
    var ordem = a.length;

    if (ordem === 1) {
        return a[0][0];
    }

    if (ordem === 2) {
        return a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[0][1] * a[1][0];
    }

    var det = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < ordem; j++) {
        det += a[0][j] * cofator(a, 0, j);
    }

    return det;
}

function cofator(a, linha, coluna) {
    var sub_matriz = [],
        ordem = a.length,
        m = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < ordem; i++) {
        sub_matriz[m] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < ordem; j++) {
            if (j !== coluna) {
                sub_matriz[m].push(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        m++;
    }

    //return Math.pow(-1, linha + coluna) * determinante(sub_matriz);
    return (coluna % 2 ? -1 : 1) * determinante(sub_matriz);
}
```

A função `determinante` é recursiva indireta (A chama B, B chama A) e usa o [Teorema de Laplace](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Laplace) para calcular o determinante de uma matriz quadrada. O teorema é aplicado sempre na primeira linha da matriz e não na linha ou coluna com o maior número de zeros, como fazemos no papel.

Exemplos de uso:

```
determinante([[1,-2,8,4,-3,1], [-2,-9,3,1,4,-4], [3,0,8,7,0,2], [5,7,1,2,5,-1], [7,-8,-6,4,0,-5], [0,-2,-8,0,0,1]])
// Retorna 1560
```

Conferir em: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%28%5B1%2C-2%2C8%2C4%2C-3%2C1%5D%2C+%5B-2%2C-9%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C-4%5D%2C+%5B3%2C0%2C8%2C7%2C0%2C2%5D%2C+%5B5%2C7%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C-1%5D%2C+%5B7%2C-8%2C-6%2C4%2C0%2C-5%5D%2C+%5B0%2C-2%2C-8%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%29

---

```
determinante([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,1]]);
// Retorna 24
```

Conferir em: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+det+%28%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C8%2C1%5D%29

---

```
determinante([[-1,-2,3], [3,3,1], [-1,2,-3]]);
// Retorna 22
```

Conferir em: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%28%5B-1%2C-2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B3%2C3%2C1%5D%2C+%5B-1%2C2%2C-3%5D%29

---

```
determinante([[8]]);
// Retorna 8
```

---

```
determinante([
    [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2],
    [0, 0, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0, 5, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 6],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
]);
// Retorna 2048
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/E9F4E/

> Nota: de fato, a implementação usando o Teorema de Laplace não é a mais eficiente, mas é fácil de visualizar e funciona bem para matrizes relativamente pequenas (ordem < 11).
>
> O jeito mais eficiente para calcular o determinante seria o método do escalonamento. [Veja esse artigo](http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~rodney/notas_de_aula/determinantes.pdf). O único porém nesse método é uma pequena perda de precisão numérica. Por exemplo, em vez de 1560, a função retorna 1559.9999999999723.

Answer (score 4):

O cálculo direto do determinante pelos cofatores é didático mas bastante ineficiente se você quer usar matrizes grandes a sério.

Uma opção melhor seria calcular a decomposição LU. Como as matrizes L e U são triangulares, o determinante de cada uma é simplesmente a multiplicação dos elementos da diagonal principal. Se A=LU então |A|=|L||U|.

O melhor mesmo seria usar a biblioteca Sylvester.js http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/matrix.html#determinant